# How to change ComboBox appearance in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have tried setting the ComboBox background/foreground/borderbrush to blue in xaml just to test, but it still stays the ugly gray color. I also tried using Resource Dictionary

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox" x:Key="CBTest">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#4a4b4d"/>
</Style>
```

But it doesnt want to change.

And this is the XAML where i use the combobox

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Style={StaticResource CBTest} Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="30" Width="200" Margin="50,0,0,0" Visibility="Hidden" Name="Emoji">
        <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="200"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ComboBoxItem Name="Happy">
            <Image Source="/SocialnoOmrezje;component/Images/emojiHappy.png" Height="20" Width="20" Name="happySlika" ></Image>
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Name="Sad">
            <Image Source="/SocialnoOmrezje;component/Images/emojiSad.png" Height="20" Width="20"></Image>
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Name="Neutral">
            <Image Source="/SocialnoOmrezje;component/Images/emojiNeutral.png" Height="20" Width="20"></Image>
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Name="Angry">
            <Image Source="/SocialnoOmrezje;component/Images/emojiAngry.png" Height="20" Width="20"></Image>
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Name="Tongue">
            <Image Source="/SocialnoOmrezje;component/Images/emojiTongue.png" Height="20" Width="20"></Image>
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Name="Surprised">
            <Image Source="/SocialnoOmrezje;component/Images/emojiSurprised.png" Height="20" Width="20"></Image>
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Name="Kiss">
            <Image Source="/SocialnoOmrezje;component/Images/emojiKiss.png" Height="20" Width="20"></Image>
        </ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Did you assign the `CBTest` Style? If you are unsure, remove the whole 
`x:Key="CBTest"` to make it a global style. Also if you search for Combobox WPF style, there are so many examples you can easily adapt.

Comment: [ComboBox Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/combobox-styles-and-templates)

Comment: @CSHarpie yes, i did use the style in the combobox

Comment: Then its not possible to tell what you are doing wrong with the amount of info you provided. We need a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you.

Comment: @CSharpie i edited and posted the XAML where i use the combobox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to context menu of the `ComboBox` from designer.  Select `Edit Template  > Edit a Copy...`
2. In the dilog box you can change name and scope of the template.
3. Once you click `OK` it will generate fairly large codes, but don't worry. Exactly same code works anyway behind scene. In that template you can change everything. To change the background locate the `ControlTemplate` for the `ToggleButton` and change `Background` and `BorderBrush` or whatever else you want.

**Step 1:**

[image: a]

**Step 2:**

[image: b]

**Step 3:**

[image: c]

Comment: Is it possible to get this part and insert it into the resource dictionary? If yes, which part exactly?

Comment: Sure, you can put it into a resource dictionary. I would put everything generated  inside `Window.Resources`.

Answer (score 0):

To customize the combo-box it is necessary to copy styles and templates listed on the Microsoft link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/combobox-styles-and-templates and start to change combo-box part colors to you preference.
Here some example below:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp5.MainWindow"
        ...
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

    <Window.Resources>

        <!--Control colors -->
        <Color x:Key="WindowColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>        
        <Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorLight">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorDark">#FF7381F9</Color>

        <Color x:Key="DisabledControlLightColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DisabledControlDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DisabledForegroundColor">#FF888888</Color>

        <Color x:Key="SelectedBackgroundColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color> 
        <Color x:Key="SelectedUnfocusedColor">#FFDDDDDD</Color>

        <Color x:Key="ControlLightColor">White</Color> 
        <Color x:Key="ControlMediumColor">#FF7381F9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ControlDarkColor">#FF211AA9</Color>

        <Color x:Key="ControlMouseOverColor">#FF3843C4</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ControlPressedColor">#FF211AA9</Color>

        <Color x:Key="GlyphColor">#FF444444</Color>
        <Color x:Key="GlyphMouseOver">sc#1, 0.004391443, 0.002428215, 0.242281124</Color>

        <!--Border colors-->
        <Color x:Key="BorderLightColor">#FFCCCCCC</Color>
        <Color x:Key="BorderMediumColor">#FF888888</Color>
        <Color x:Key="BorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

        <Color x:Key="PressedBorderLightColor">#FF888888</Color>
        <Color x:Key="PressedBorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

        <Color x:Key="DisabledBorderLightColor">#FFAAAAAA</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DisabledBorderDarkColor">#FF888888</Color>

        <Color x:Key="DefaultBorderBrushDarkColor">Black</Color>

        <!--Control-specific resources.-->
        <Color x:Key="HeaderTopColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DatagridCurrentCellBorderColor">Black</Color>
        <Color x:Key="SliderTrackDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>

        <Color x:Key="NavButtonFrameColor">#FF3843C4</Color>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MenuPopupBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}" Offset="0.5" />
            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndicatorAnimatedFill" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#000000FF" Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#600000FF" Offset="0.4" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#600000FF" Offset="0.6" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#000000FF" Offset="1" />
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>


        <!-- ControlTemplate -->
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                                  Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ControlMouseOverColor}" />
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" 
                                                                  Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource DisabledControlDarkColor}" />
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundColor}" />
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" 
                                                                  Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderDarkColor}" />
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" 
                                                                  Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ControlPressedColor}" />
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate" />
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <Border x:Name="Border" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" CornerRadius="2" BorderThickness="1">
                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderLightColor}" Offset="0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderDarkColor}" Offset="1" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Border.BorderBrush>
                    <Border.Background>

                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                <GradientStopCollection>
                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}" Offset="1.0" />
                                </GradientStopCollection>
                            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>

                    </Border.Background>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="2,0,0,2" Margin="1" >
                    <Border.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"/>
                    </Border.Background>
                </Border>
                <Path x:Name="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z" >
                    <Path.Fill>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource GlyphColor}"/>
                    </Path.Fill>
                </Path>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
        </ControlTemplate>

        <Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120" />
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundColor}" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="EditStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Editable">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentSite">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Uneditable" />
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton" Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" Grid.Column="2" Focusable="false" ClickMode="Press" 
                                              IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>

                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" 
                                                  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                                                  ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                                                  Margin="3,3,23,3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            </ContentPresenter>

                            <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" Style="{x:Null}" Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                         VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="3,3,23,3" Focusable="True" Background="Transparent" Visibility="Hidden" 
                                         IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}" />

                            <Popup x:Name="Popup" Placement="Bottom" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Slide">
                                <Grid x:Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                    <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderThickness="1">
                                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource BorderMediumColor}" />
                                        </Border.BorderBrush>
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
                                        </Border.Background>
                                    </Border>
                                    <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Grid>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4" />
                                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                        <Border x:Name="Border" Padding="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="Transparent">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundColor}" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SelectedUnfocusedColor}" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Ellipse.Visibility" Value="Hidden">
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>

                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="False"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="Red"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="#A826A0DA"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="#3D26A0DA"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="#FF26A0DA"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="Red"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="#99006CD9"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="False"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="#FFCBE8F6"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="#FFDADADA"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="#FF26A0DA"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="Red"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="#FF26A0DA"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ComboBox x:Name="PlayersComboBox" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Players}" Margin="5,5,5,0" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Pay attention that this generic example includes gradient colors that it is possible to change.