# WPF Xaml ComboBox and DataPicker - How to change BorderBrush with MultiDataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to change a BorderBrush of my DataPicker and ComboBox with MultiDataTrigger. I have 3 conditions.
It's work for TextBox and TextBlock but the same code don't work for my DatePicker and ComboBox. Do you know why please? My code :

```
 <ComboBox.Style>
      <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
      <Style.Triggers>
          <MultiDataTrigger>
             <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=ProgramNameComboBox, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="True" />
                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=ProgramNameComboBox, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="" />
                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=SaveLabel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content}" Value="Save" />
             </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
             <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
          </MultiDataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
</ComboBox.Style>
```

---

```
<DatePicker x:Name="StartDateDataPicker" IsEnabled="{Binding IsRowEnabled}" SelectedDate="{Binding StartDate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" >     <!--BorderBrush="{Binding StartDateBorderBrushColor}"-->
    <DatePicker.Style>
        <Style TargetType="DatePicker">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=StartDateDataPicker, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="True" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=StartDateDataPicker, Path=SelectedDate}" Value="null" (I also tried : "01/01/0001") />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=SaveLabel, Path=Content}" Value="Save" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DatePicker.Style>
</DatePicker>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you use `ElementName` with control itself?

Comment: on the site where I learned it so recommend.. :
https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/fr/94/les-styles/wpf-multitrigger-and-multidatatrigger/

Answer (score 0):

`null` is represented as `{x:Null}` in XAML:

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=StartDateDataPicker, Path=SelectedDate}"
           Value="{x:Null}" />
```

There is however [more work](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/04/30/changing-the-background-colour-of-a-combobox-in-wpf-on-windows-8/) required to change the border of a `ComboBox`. You need to define your own `ControlTemplate` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59631330/7252182).

Comment: Thanks, but even if I just leave one condition it does not work, I think that for combobox and Datepicker it works differently, but.. how? :/

Comment: Because they have different control templates. See my edit.